# I modified Prometheus YML. How can I make the modification take effect without restarting docker compose？

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
    - 9090:9090
    command:
    - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml 
    - --web.enable-lifecycle
    volumes:
    - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro
```

`prometheus.yml`

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: cadvisor
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - cadvisor:8080
- job_name: node
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['127.0.0.1:9100']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restart the `prometheus` service:

```sh
docker-compose restart prometheus
```

You have the `--web-enable-lifecycle` flag set correctly on the container so you **should** be able to `POST` to the Prometheus `reload` endpoint:

```sh
curl --request POST http://localhost:9090/-/reload
```

Comment: thank u very much.i tried the reload,it worded.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped.